# How to access form nested ng-include scope/fields?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I looked around and can't find the same problem that I have.
Like a lot of people ng-include creates a new child scope that can't propagate to parent.
I have a generic template that I want to use with different form actions but can't since it doesn't receive the data from ng-include.
Here is the code:

```
<form ng-controller='FormCtrl' name="form1" ng-submit="treatForm1(data)"><div ng-include src="'template'"></div></form>
<form ng-controller='FormCtrl' name="form2" ng-submit="treatForm2(data)"><div ng-include src="'template'"></div></form>
```

I can't use notations like vm. or form., unfortunately.
Is there a way to get the ng-include scope on submit? I tried this, $parent, nada.

Comment: Is it different form action or different controller method?

Comment: Same controller, just different controller method on submit, example save for 1 and update for the other one 2 (not my case though)

Comment: But where are those methods called?

Comment: In the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) to send it up to the parent?

Comment: That's a nice idea although dirty, I'm not a big fan of listening for emits :s. Thanks.